# Using an inverse operator to find a particular solution to a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am just learning about inverse operators in solving a differential equation, but I don't understand exactly how they work. For example, find a particular solution to

$$4y''-3y'+9y=5x^2$$

using inverse operators.

The above equation is equivalent to

$$(4D^2-3D+9)y=5x^2$$

Now the way to solve this would be to use the inverse operator as follows:

$$y_p=(4D^2-3D+9)^{-1}5x^2$$
or

$$y_p=\frac {1}{4D^2-3D+9}5x^2$$

The book I am reading uses "simple division" and arrives at a result, but I don't quite understand how that works.

*What is a step-by-step method to solve the above problem?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that 
$$4D^2 - 3D + 9 = \left [D - \left ( \frac{3}{8} (1 - i \sqrt{15} )\right)\right ] \left [D - \left ( \frac{3}{8} (1 + i \sqrt{15} )\right)\right ]  $$
Also note that
$$ \frac{1}{-a( 1 - D /a )} = -\frac{1}{a} \left ( 1 + \frac{D}{a} + \frac{D^2}{a^2} + \ldots \right) $$
Thus to find $y_p$, we simply have to compute ( calling the roots $\lambda_\pm = 3/8 ( 1 \pm i \sqrt{15})$)
$$ y_p = \frac{1}{4D^2 - 3D + 9} 5x^2 = \frac{1}{ | \lambda_\pm|^2} \frac{1}{1- D/\lambda_+} \frac{ 1}{1 - D / \lambda_-} 5x^2= \frac{1}{|\lambda_\pm|^2}\left ( 1 + \frac{D}{\lambda_+} + \frac{D^2}{\lambda_+^2} \right ) \left ( 1 + \frac{D}{\lambda_-} + \frac{D^2}{\lambda_-^2} \right) 5x^2 = \frac{5}{|\lambda_\pm|^2} \left ( 1+ \frac{ \lambda_+ + \lambda_-}{|\lambda_\pm|^2} D + \frac{(\lambda_- + \lambda_+)^2} {|\lambda_\pm|^4 } D^2 \right )  x^2$$
Now you just have to evaluate the derivatives and you're done. (where $|\lambda_\pm|^2 = \lambda_+ \lambda_-$)

Note that I stopped at the second differential operator since $D^3 ( 5x^2) = 0$.

Comment: Although this method is correct, it may become exceedingly difficult if one has to find the roots of a 5th or 6th degree operator. Is there an easier way?

Comment: There are "easier" ways, but the simple division you're referring to most definitely means my " also note that... " line. Notice the only real computation I've done is find the roots. which in itself contains the homogenous solution as well. This method only works for constant coeffient ode's which need you to compute the roots of the corresponding characteristic equation.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!